# How can i save custom field value in customer_entity table in Magento 2 using observer

Tags: php, magento2, observers

Below is my observer code:

```
<?php

class CustomerOrderCountObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var customerFactory
     */
    private $customerFactory;

    /**
     * 
     * @param CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
          $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Upgrade customer password hash when customer has logged in
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderInstance = $observer->getEvent()->getdata();
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getdata('order_ids');
        $orderCount = is_array($orderIds)?count($orderIds):0;
        $orderId = current($orderIds);
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

        if($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($session->getCustomerId());
            $orderCount = $orderCount + $customer->getOrderCount();
            $customer->setOrderCount($orderCount);
            $customer->save($customer);
        } 
    }
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong with this. It is not saving the customer column value `order_count`

Comment: DId you get Solution for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving using the customer data changes using a resourceModel instead of saving using the model

```
$customerResourceModel->save($customer);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try loading customer from model

```
 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($session->getCustomerId());
```

Comment: i wanna to get the solution regarding Magento 2 !  by the way Thanks